# Checking the lyrics: Michael Lydon's _Love at First Sight_

Tags: lyrics

I am listening Michael Lydon's *Love at First Sight*

The following lyrics are generated automatically by youtube.
Could anyone help me check it? Thanks.

(A) One night in June big bad mood
Chinese lanterns twinkle in bright
Now what was the tune that big band was pruning
Must have been love at first sight

(B) We danced till three on the balcony
Dawn for the stars to flight
Honeysuckle breeze whispering leaves
Must have been love at first sight

(C) By now we had a while
To look each other over
??? what time could bring two lovers
That night at the lake was no mistake
The years disappeared you are my year

Darlin
That was the tune that big band was pruning
Must have been love at first sight

(C)

(A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrections to the lyrics highlighted in bold below:

(A) One night in June big bad **moon**
Chinese lanterns twinkle in bright
Now what was the tune that big band was **crooning**
Must have been love at first sight

(B) We danced till three on the balcony
Dawn for the stars to flight
Honeysuckle breeze whispering leaves
Must have been love at first sight

(C) By now we had a while
To look each other over
**We've seen** what time could bring two lovers
That night at the lake was no mistake
The years **disappear when you hum in my ear**

Darlin
That was the tune that big band was **crooning**
Must have been love at first sight

(C)

(A)

Comment: Thanks for your help. By the way. What does a "big bad moon" mean? Is it a slang or a metaphor?

Comment: I'm not sure. It could be an allusion to "Bad Moon Rising" by Credence Clearwater Revival (http://riverising.tripod.com/john-interviews/rollingstone2.html). Alternatively, it could simply be in the lyrics to provide a rhyme with "June".